# Rewrite a function to find an object by a matching id inside an array, update a value and set a react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The function below receiving a rating value inside an object. While ID or Question stay intact, the rating value can be updated. As a result a React state value should be updated.
Is there a way to make this function look prettier/concise while just using a vanilla javascript.

```
  ratingCompleted = ({ rating, question, id }) => {
    let array = this.state.ratingResponses;
    const index = array.findIndex(elem => elem.id == id);

    if (index === -1) {
      array.push({ rating, question, id });
      this.setState({ ratingResponses: array });
    } else {
      array.map(object => {
        if (object.id === id) {
          object.rating = rating;
          return object;
        } else {
          return object;
        }
      });
      this.setState({ ratingResponses: array });
    }
  };
```

Comment: This doesn't make it look any nicer, but you should change `let array = this.state.ratingResponses;` to `let array = [...this.state.ratingResponses];` so it does not mutate state when calling `push`.

Comment: Your `array.map` also mutates the nested objects. `map` returns a new array, and is intended to be used as such. Anytime you catch yourself not using the returned value, its a sign you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

## Make sure you spread to stop mutations

This could be a little cleaner but i thought I would show each step.

```
const array = [...this.state.ratingResponses]; // spread this so as to make a copy
let updatedArray;


const hasRatingAlready = array.some(item => item.id === id);

if (!hasRatingAlready) {
  updatedArray = [...array, { rating, question, id }];
} else {
  updatedArray = array.map(item => item.id === id ? {...item, rating} : item);
}

this.setState({ ratingResponses: updatedArray });
```

Comment: Thanks Joe lloyd and @Brian-Thompson I'lll take a look at mutation issues in my code closer.